# ActiveRecord, validates_uniqueness_of :name not catching non-uniquness if I have a capitalize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a simple capitalize method so that when user submits a new band in the band page it returns it with the first letter capitalized.
Inside my `Band` class I also have a validates_uniqueness_of `:band_name` to see if there is already a `band` with the same entry. See code below:

```
  class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :venues
    validates :band_name, :presence => true
    before_save :title_case
    validates_uniqueness_of :band_name

  private

    def title_case
      self.band_name.capitalize!
    end

  end
```

So if I type in `someband`, it creates it and displays it as `Someband`. If I type `someband` again, `ActiveRecord` sees it as unique and I'll get another `Someband`. The only way it works is if I type `Someband`. How would I remedy this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this

`validates_uniqueness_of :band_name, :case_sensitive :false, allow_blank: false`

Take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html

> :case_sensitive - Looks for an exact match. Ignored by non-text
>   columns (true by default).

Comment: Thanks. I thought I did take a through look but this one must have missed my eyes.

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help. Happy Hacking

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is because validations happen before the `before_save` callbacks are triggered. Check out the list of [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for the order in which things are called.

[MZaragoza's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32281080/5021779) is a great option for making your validation work regardless of what casing your users might enter. It will prevent things like "someband" and "SomeBand" from being added. I recommend including that as part of your solution.

Another option very similar to the code you already have is to switch to using the `before_validation` callback:

```
before_validation :title_case
```

I highly recommend using the `before_validation` callbacks instead of `before_save` callbacks whenever data changes that may be relevant to your validation rules, regardless of what other changes you make. That ensures that you are checking that actual state of the model that you plan to save to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute setter instead of `before_save` callback to capitalize your value without postponing.

```
def band_name=(value)
  self['band_name'] = value && value.mb_chars.capitalize
end
```